# Seaborn custom range heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I need to build custom seaborn heatmap-like plot according to these requirements:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0.3, 0.8, 1.3], 
                   "B": [4, 9, 15], 
                   "C": [650, 780, 900]})

df_info = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["min", "max"],
                   "A": [0.5, 0.9], 
                   "B": [6, 10], 
                   "C": [850, 880]})
df_info = df_info.set_index('id')
```

**df**

```
    A      B    C
0   0.3    4    650
1   0.8    9    780
2   1.3    15   900
```

**df_info**

```
id      A      B    C
            
min     0.5    6    850
max     0.9    10   880
```

Each value within `df` is supposed to be within a range defined in `df_info`.
For example the values for the column `A` are considered normal if they are within 0.5 and 0.9.   Values that are outside the range should be colorized using a custom heatmap.

In particular:

- Values that fall within the range defined for each column should **not** be colorized, plain black text on white background cell.
- Values lower than `min` for that column should be colorized, for example in blue. The lower their values from the min the darker the shade of blue.
- Values higher than `max` for that column should be colorized, for example in red. The higher their values from the max the darker the shade of red.

**Q:** I wouldn't know how to approach this with a standard heatmap, I'm not even sure I can accomplish this with a heatmap plot. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, a heatmap can only have one scale of values. I would suggest normalizing the data you have in the `df` dataframe so the values in every column follow:

- between `0` and `1` if the value is between `df_info`'s `min` `max`
- below `0` if the value is below `df_info`'s `min`
- above `1` if the value is above `df_info`'s `max`

To normalize your dataframe use :

```py
for col in df:
    df[col] = (df[col] - df_info[col]['min']) / (df_info[col]['max'] - df_info[col]['min'])
```

Finally, to create the color-coded heatmap use :

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

vmin = df.min().min()
vmax = df.max().max()

colors = [[0, 'darkblue'],
          [- vmin / (vmax - vmin), 'white'],
          [(1 - vmin)/ (vmax - vmin), 'white'],
          [1, 'darkred']]

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', colors)
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

The additional calculations with `vmin` and `vmax` allow a dynamic scaling of the colormap depending on the differences with the minimums and maximums.

Using your input dataframe we have the following heatmap:
[image]

Comment: very good answer! Is it possible to apply a diverging palette to this solution or does it only work with a LinearSegmentedColormap?

Comment: It seems that `seaborn.diverging_palette` center's itself on `(max + min) / 2` which won't always be your case if you use my implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, another question: how would I colorize NaN values with different color, for example black? I guess I should specify it in the colors array but I'm not sure I understand its structure. Any link to explain this array?

Comment: `seaborn` manages automatically `nan` values, by default `nan` values are displayed as white boxes, to change this use : `sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax).set_facecolor('black')`. The `facecolor` represents the background color.

Comment: @Leonardo If this answers your question, please mark my response as 'Answer'